# How to sum all the keys of a dictionary value to the same dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Let's say I have a dictionary that has
{'a' : '0',
 'b' : '2',
 'a' : '3',
 'b' : '5',}

I want the dictionary to say {'a' : '3'
                              'b' : '7'}

How would I do this ?

Comment: That is an invalid dictionary. You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary. If you actually output that dictionary as is, you will get something like: `{'b': '5', 'a': '3'}`

Answer (score 1):

You can't create dictionary which contains the same key twice. The definition of the dictionary is that you can store in it every key-value option only once.